Calibrating the commercial bar-type load cell for measuring weight at tilt
The commercial hobbyist bar-type load cell you buy at ebay for about 3 dollars or so has 4 strain gauges (two at the top and two at the bottom) for measuring weight that is perpendicular to the load cell downwards. Hence they are usually measuring at a single axis. However, I am planning to use it for multiple-axis measurement. This means my weight is going to be tilted at an angle between 0 and 30 degrees. The tilt can be both on a pitch and roll. I am using a MPU6050 unit to measure the angle.
Of course, I can buy a multi-axis load cell, but they are usually expensive, and I was wondering, out of interest, if the single load cell can be calibrated, virtually using CAD simulation for example, to compensate for the angles and give a similar result to the multi-axis load cell?
I tried compensating using trigonometric functions. It seems to be ok but the error is still high.
Any help is very much appreciated.

So how have you analysed the situation to find out where the errors are?

@SolarMike What I did is that I used a standard known load and changed the angles and took the readings accordingly by applying the load on the pitch only and then roll only. Then I plotted and it and compared it to both the standard weight and the non-compensated output. It looks much better than the un-compensated output but it still could be better compared to the known load ( what it should look like).
